# Can synonym replace Trigger

Tags: hibernate, synonym

My purpose is to create a **synonym** in order to replace the use of **trigger**.

My java project have to made changes on that synonym on real time.

I created a public synonym like that `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM CLASSE_SYNO FOR DB2.CLASSE`;
As result, all the datas on **DB2.CLASSE** are inserted on **DB1.CLASSE_SYNO**.
But, once I run the spring-mvc project, all the datas on **DB1.CLASSE_SYNO** are deleted.
Knowing that in `persistence.xml`, I made:

```
<properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/> 
        <property name="hibernate.synonyms" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.includeSynonyms" value="true"/>
    </properties>
```

Have you please any idea about solving that issue ?. Big thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrade your Hibernate.

Try `Hibernate 4.3` or later.

HTH.